# Using Web http services in android

Tags: xml, http

Another Android newbie question...
I found a way to package my WCF soap services as Web http services.  The android client provides an http url and gets back XML.  Does Android have classes (in .Net its called WebClient) to post http urls and classes to process XML?  What are those classes?

thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple ways to do the HTTP connection part of it, and they're written up on the Android Dev Blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Myself, I prefer the HttpURLConnection.